# What do you do when a moderator doesnt respond to the private message chain?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I received a PM from a moderator about a couple of my posts, and was told that they violated Stack Overflow terms. When I replied back with questions to understand how I can better comply with the terms, I did not get a reply. I'm worried continuing to operate without knowing will result in a timed ban. How do i get the moderator to reply back?

Comment: Don't expect a response if this was a warning to stop spamming the site with links to your company.  Everybody is expected to know what spam means.  It never was meat.

Comment: "When I replied back with questions to understand how I can better comply with the terms, I did not get a reply." Please post those questions here on Meta. You are looking for guidance to improve your posts, and there's absolutely no reason for that discussion to be private, others may benefit from it. The whole community - not just the mod that contacted you - would be happy to help.

Comment: Why are people down voting this? Because it had to do with spam? If it _was_ because of that, you're ridiculous.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, the moderator may not have replied because he believed the original message contained enough information to answer your follow-on questions.

You were messaged because all 10 of the answers you've left, dating back to January, promoted the services of Distil Networks. In none of these answers did you note that you work for this company, nor did you indicate as such in your profile. As explained in the [help center link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) you were provided:

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as
>   spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to
>   be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must
>   disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product
>   or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our
>   advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for
>   details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source
>   projects and non-profit organizations.

Your answers ran afoul of both the self-disclosure requirements (especially since you phrased them to come off like you were an uninvested third party) and the fact that a significant percentage were promoting your company.

However, I have to say that you do have some good information in your deleted answers that is unrelated to your company's products. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17707203/19679), for example, gives some good background on the problem to be solved and is only spoiled by the promotion in the last paragraph. The whole point of your presence here shouldn't be to sell your services, it should be to answer technical questions. If the last paragraph was removed, I could see undeleting that. Also, you could give proper disclosure there and limit the amount of promotion you did for your company in your other answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My biggest question was, if I disclose my affiliation with the company does that satisfy the no spamming policy?

Comment: @RamiE - In general, but the whole reason for all of your answers can't be to promote your company. In the answer I point to above, the last paragraph didn't need to be there for it to be a complete answer. If you're able to contribute good answers, and only occasionally mentioning your product (with full disclosure) as a potential solution to the problem asked, I'd probably be fine with that. I can't speak for everyone else, though, because some people are pretty hard on any kind of self-promotion. Still, if on balance you're contributing good information, people will support you.

Answer (score 8):

I'll be honest, normally moderators do not reply back to a mod message reply. However, if you had specific questions, all moderators of the site are notified when you reply and they should respond if they are going to.

The moderator message system is not a general use Private Message system, it's reserved for disciplinary action only. Which means you've done something that violates site policy. Seeing as you don't have any undeleted questions or answers anywhere I'd have to guess and I'd rather not.

If you have a question about site policy then the appropriate meta is the place to go. Here or SF's meta will be good places to get answers about any site policy issue you have questions about.

If you do not receive a response in a timely manner and still want one, then there is a "contact us" link at the bottom of every page. You may choose the "other" option to email the SE community team.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason not to respond in general? Is that out of sense of "that usually won't go anywhere positive"?

Comment: @Bart Responding creates the same amount of documentation as sending the first message (CC'ed to all mods _and_ SE, permanent mark on the user's account). Most of the times, responding simply isn't worth the trouble, mod messages aren't meant for back and forth communication. If a user is interested in getting further guidance on the issue they were contacted for - or any other issue, really - there's always Meta.

Comment: I see @Yannis. Sounds reasonable. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

All communications between a user and a mod using the mod messaging system are copied to all other moderators on the site, and to probably a dozen other people at SE corporate.  They can be very disruptive, so mod messages are only used to address severe issues.

In the immortal words of Jeff Atwood, we only use mod messages when "killing kittens may be involved."

Comment: Curiously, while I eat kittens for breakfast every day, I've never been mod messaged.

Comment: @Yannis If you bite into them while they're still alive, that would get you past the radar.